# How to create a card view in activity A on button click from Activity B

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

In my project the requirement is to create a **recycler view -> card view** inactivity A when information is filled and the button is pressed in activity B.

The filled information in activity B should be passed to Activity A **recycler view -> card view**.

I know how to create a card view on button click but don't have an answer to my question.

I'm new to android development and kindly help me with solutions for this. Million thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first show **Activity A** then show **Activity B** so you can use   [ActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)   but if you first show **Activity B** and user fill the information then show **Activity A** you can pass data with Intent in **Activity B** :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
intent.putExtra("information_name", "Saptha");
intent.putExtra("information_last_name", "Clans"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

then in your **Activity A** get data like this and insert in your list :

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("information_name");
String lastName = getIntent().getStringExtra("nformation_last_name");
```

Comment: @SapthaClans ,  in activityForResult of  Activity A you can do this